# How to take a certain set of characters from a string and use those as a unicode value?

Tags: java, string, unicode, unicode-string

[Java] So I have this hexadecimal: 0x6c6c6548. I need to take two characters out at a time, use those two characters to get a unicode value and then concatenate them all into a string.

My idea was to take the last two digits using the charAt() method, and then adding them to a string starting with "\u00", but that doesn't work because the compiler thinks of the slash as an escape and you can't add another slash in front of the first because then it just prints a slash and doesn't convert it to unicode.

So like I need to take the 48 out and somehow convert it to it's unicode value, which is 'H' and then do that for all the pairs and put them into one string.

Comment: Two character could represent at most one byte.  You'll need to clarify, because that itself doesn't seem like Unicode.  What about illegal values (there are some in that range), what do you do about them?  How are values greater than 127 interpreted?

Comment: The unicode value for 'H' is 0048. 0065 would be 'e' and 006c would be 'l'. I'm not working with anything past three digits so the first two digits of the value will always be 00.

Comment: What about the Unicode value 0080, what does that correspond to?  And 0048 for H is four characters, not two.

Comment: 0080 is a space. I need to pull the 48 out of 0x6c6c6548, then add that to the end of 00, which will make 0048 and somehow get that converted to it's unicode value which is 'H'.

Comment: 80 is not a space.  It's reserved and illegal in every encoding scheme I know of.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Either way, I know I won't have to worry about it.

Comment: so you only want to deal with unicode >= 0xff and all illegal codes will be filtered out already ?

Comment: Yes, I will only be working with 4 digit values, but all with start 00.

Comment: char unicode = (char)Integer.valueOf("004c", 16);

Comment: you may even omit the leading "00"

Comment: @Oncaphillis I tried that and it said incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to char.

Comment: Ups too much C recently. char unicode = Character.toChars(Integer.valueOf("4c",16))[0]; should be sufficient. It throws an exception if the unicode is illegal and returns a two char sequence if the char belongs to the supplemental code pages which Java has to map to two chars.